# Error retrieving metadata for entities of type: Layout. Error message: record limit reached. cannot submit more than 10 records in this operation

Tags: apex, metadata-api, metadata, governorlimits

We are using Lightning Aura component to display tabs dynamically based on the record types and Layouts.

When trying to retrieve more than 10 records using Metadata.Operations.retrieve in the code it is throwing below error
**System.UnexpectedException: Error retrieving metadata for entities of type: Layout. Error message: record limit reached. cannot submit more than 10 records in this operation**

Is there any workaround to resolve this issue?

```
 for(RecordSettings__mdt tabName : [Select MasterLabel, DeveloperName from RecordSettings__mdt where Status__c = 'Active'])
        {
            layoutsName.add(Opportunity+'-'+tabName.MasterLabel);
        }
        for(Metadata.Metadata layout : Metadata.Operations.retrieve(Metadata.MetadataType.Layout, layoutsName)){ ***// When metadata type has more than 10 records it is throwing error***
            Metadata.Layout layoutMd = (Metadata.Layout) layout;    
            String tab = layoutMd.fullName.substringAfterLast('__c-');
            for(Metadata.LayoutSection section : layoutMd.layoutSections) {
                if(section.label != 'Custom Links'){ 
                    if(tabSec.containsKey(tab)){
                        List<String> sections = tabSec.get(tab);
                        if(sectionNames.contains(section.label)){
                            sections.add(section.label);
                        }
                        tabSec.put(tab,sections);
                    }else{
                        List<String> sections = new List<String>();
                        if(sectionNames.contains(section.label)){
                            sections.add(section.label);
                        }
                        tabSec.put(tab,sections);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return tabSec;
    }
```

Comment: could you try boxcar'ing it? build a list of lists where each sublist is no more than 10 elements in size and then call `.retrieve` n times, where n is the size of the outer list? Example 21 layouts is represented as a list of three elements where [0] has layouts 1-10, [1] has layouts 11-20; [2] has layout 21)

Comment: @cropredy thanks for your response, can you pls elaborate or provide any example?

Comment: Loop through `layoutNames` until you get to 10 elements, stuffing each into a new list `workItems` then call `Meatdata.Operations.retrieve` on `workItems`; then clear `workItems` and loop through the next 10 elements of `layoutNames`, etc. I don't know if this resolves the exception but is worth trying